# Keep Facebook access after app is killed iOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, facebook, facebook-access-token

I'm developing an iOS9 app in Swift and using the latest Facebook SDK for login. I have followed the documentation and the login is working fine except it fails to keep the facebook access token upon relaunch. Specifically, when I kill the app both on a simulator and on an actual device and then restart the app, I have to log in again for Facebook on the same device despite having logged in before. When I continue logging in, it links to facebook with the message: "You have already authorized Name of app".

According to the Facebook SDK docs, when logged in once the app should cache the FBSDKAccessToken and it should not expire immediately when the user quits and relaunches the app.

I have the code below in my AppDelegate.Swift :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
```

And I do the check below in my viewDidLoad():

```
if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil){}
```

Anyone know why restarting the app makes the AccessToken nil?

---

**Edit:**

I'm also getting this error when I click on my Facebook login button. I am unsure of whether this is a cause of the above issue. :

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth://authorize/?client_id=1068860826518986&default_audience=friends&display=touch&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A1460515013815%7D&legacy_override=v2.4&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&
        response_type=token%2Csigned_request&return_scopes=true&scope=public_profile%2Cema
        il%2Cuser_friends&sdk=ios&sdk_version=4.4.0&state=%7B%22challenge%22%3A%22YXJWy0wjHG2r4lnyAe%5C%2FMjqM3xy4%3D%22%2C%220_auth_logger_id%22%3A%22591AC45B-AB19-49AE-A994-
        851223E03265%22%2C%22com.facebook.sdk_client_state%22%3Atrue%2C%223_method%22%3A0%7D" 

    - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fbauth"
```

Comment: Check in `Info.plist` that you have `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `YES`

Comment: @bitsoverflow Yes, I have done that as well. Still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

its delete the user defaults that it is saved. So when you restart the app you have to login again.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you don't have any code which is making logOut() of FBSDKLoginManager on application terminate method as below**

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logOut()
}
```

If such code is there then on device restart, your access token is no longer valid.